# How to view VS 2017 message about missing framework that was installed

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I created a blank UWP app using Visual Studio 2017 Community.  When I ran the app using F5, there was a message that was briefly displayed saying "installing missing framework..." with the specific name of the missing package.  But once the application started running, the message disappeared.  I checked the output and immediate windows, but could not find the message.  I also checked add/remove programs, but did not see any new framework that was installed.

How can I find out what missing component was just installed on-demand?

(I am on Windows 10 1809.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the package dependencies when you create an APPX package in Visual Studio. Right-click your UWP project, choose **Store** and **Create app packages...**. In the dialog choose **sideloading** option:

[image: Sideloading]

Finish the process and a **AppPackages** folder will be created in your project folder. Here you will find your generated package folder and inside a folder **Dependencies**. This contains all dependencies that your app requires to be installed on the target machine.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't even aware of the Store option!  It turns out that package is called Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2.  However, on disk it has a longer name: Microsoft.NET.CoreFramework.Debug.2.2_2.2.27129.1_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe.xml

Comment: Yes, that is apparently a debug helper for UWP :-) . This won't be part of the package when you do a Release build

Comment: How did you become an expert in UWP, by trial/error or how? Could you share any tips. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, what's a debug helper?

Comment: I wouldn't call myself an expert :-). I just like UWP and enjoy discovering things about it. Actually, answering questions here is a great way to learn, as you usually learn something new in the process :-) .

Comment: Regarding the debug helper - that's not an official term, it is just my guess that it is a library that Visual Studio uses for debugging purposes. Unfortunately there aren't many mentions of the library on the web, so it is probably used internally